# NOR Gate from XOR and And

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-operations

I am trying to create a 2-input NOR Gate only from XOR and AND Gates. however I am stuck. The output must be NOT X AND NOT Y as the definition of a NOR GATE but I can not seem to understand how to get it.

Comment: Is there a reason why NAND gates can not be used? I have not given this any serious consideration yet, but i have never seen a NOR constructed of anything else than NANDs if it is outside of silicon...

Comment: XOR and AND form a universal set of gates which I completed a proof of. The restrictions for this problem are that the NOR gate only excepts 2-inputs and it must only use AND and XOR Gates. If It used NAND gates I would of completed this problem already haha.

Comment: I doubt that XOR and AND form a functionally complete set. How do you implement an inverter?

Comment: NOT-X = X XOR 1 = X'(1) + X(1)' = X' + X(0) = X'

Comment: @FutureUIUXDeveloper  Yes, `X ^ 1 = !X`

Comment: The usual definition of functional completeness does not include the usage of constant values like 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work.

```
(A XOR 1) AND (B XOR 1)
```

Comment: yes, since `A XOR 1 == NOT A`, the rest follows from a trivial application of De Morgan's Law  - `(NOT A) AND (NOT B) == NOT (A OR B)`

Comment: Thank You Harish! Can't believe It was right in my face.